# DataTables Row Grouping with Dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, datatables

I'm trying **DataTables Row Grouping**.. I followed the example below and its working great

[Row grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)

Just would like to know it is possible to make a drop down and select data based on the grouping.

if i select London it will show all staff for London and so on...

otherwise it will show all data..

is this possible with DataTables ? How do I implement this..?

TQVM much for the input

Comment: just sw this [link](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) how do i integrate with row grouping and i only want 1 select drop down and put it at top of page

Comment: nevermind i used this  : https://jsfiddle.net/2q720zj6/4/